# Why root's default shell is configured differently with other normal user account's default shell?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, security, freebsd, users

As I know, `root`'s default shell is configured `csh` and normal user's default shell is `sh` in FreeBSD. And in Ubuntu, `root` is `dash`, normal user is `bash`. (refer: https://serverfault.com/questions/239535/whats-the-ubuntus-default-shell/239537#239537)

Why are they configured differently?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell - Dash, is faster, Bash has more features for the end-user.  Since you should almost never be using root shell normally, you don't really need all the features of bash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [FAQ](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/faq/security.html):

In FreeBSD's case, the reason is that `csh` is the only shell "guaranteed" to be on the base filesystem (stuff from `ports` usually winds up in `/usr/local/bin`, which defaults to a different filesystem). This is important because you don't ever want there to be a situation where `root` can't log in because it's using a shell on a different (unmounted) filesystem.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is guaranteed available too. But `csh` has better interactive features, plus it's become an accepted tradition. Other BSDs don't follow it; OpenBSD's root's shell is `/bin/ksh` (a pdksh derivative).

Comment: @Gilles Right. I chose `ksh` as `root`'s shell on my NetBSD VPS. I was just repeating the "official" explanation. Frankly, `csh` is a big reason I like having `toor` around: I much prefer `bash` or `zsh` myself.