# different shell for root and non-root user

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, users

When I ssh as root, my shell is `bash`, but when it's a non-root user it is `sh`. How can I make them both to use `bash`?
This actually goes against the logic in this question: [Why root's default shell is configured differently with other normal user account's default shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7938/why-roots-default-shell-is-configured-differently-with-other-normal-user-account)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see `man usermod`.

An example would be `sudo usermod -s /bin/bash username`.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know your default shell is defined in `/etc/passwd` (as decided at user creation). Change `/etc/passwd` on the target machine to reflect your choice.

Comment: OMG thanks. I used useradd, so that's why it was configured to `sh`. If you use adduser, it will be `bash` on Ubuntu.

Comment: @fortress You can use the `-s` option to set the shell at user creation time.

Answer (score 3):

The command `chsh(1)` is used to change a user's shell. The system can be set up to allow only certain shells by listing the allowed shells in `/etc/shells`. This does not need root privileges, but a user can only change their shell.

You will need to enter your password (not root) to change your shell, unless you are root, in which case no password is needed and you can set any program to be used as a user's shell (ignoring `/etc/shells`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this either while creating the user with the option `useradd -s /bin/bash`, or later with `usermod -s /bin/bash` [as suggested by can](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11485/different-shell-for-root-and-non-root-user/11491#11491), or by modifying the `/etc/passwd` file [as suggested by asoundmove](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11485/different-shell-for-root-and-non-root-user/11488#11488). But if you are looking for another solution, then I suggest looking for the file `/etc/default/useradd` and modifying it according to your need. If you change the line `SHELL=/bin/bash`, it will apply to every new user. Also have a look at `/etc/login.defs` file.